# how to create separate Logs for each user using Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

We are creating application log using Log4j and its being appended into a File whose path is provided in its logger-config file.

We are in a process to create log for each user that logs into the system. And this system is in production and application users are between 300-500 logged in simultaneously.
Well this user based logging will be a Rule based and will be for particular users only (For monitoring any errors/Exceptions)

Currently i just want to know how can we create individual file logs for each user using Log4j with JAVA.

Moreover i want to know if there are other APIs that provide such options?

Comment: You could create a different Logger for each user: Logger.getLogger(username)

Answer (score 0):

In a standalone java program / fat-client you can use the "${user.name}" variable in your log4j.properties if every user runs the application with a different os-user name.

```
log_path=./
log_foldername=logs/
log_prefix=logfileprefix_${user.name}_logfilesuffix

log4j.appender.LogDebug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LogDebug.File=${log_path}${log_foldername}${log_prefix}_LogDebug.txt
log4j.appender.LogDebug.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.LogDebug.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.LogDebug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LogDebug.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-20t]-[%d] %-5p %c.%M():%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.LogDebug.threshold=debug
```

Comment: and how to set the ${user.name} inside java class. Also if i make a login page and attach beans on the fields say user/pass. and press login that "user" file should be created and at the same time second user will login in and 2nd user should have separate file not appended to the first one

Comment: Ah I assumed that you have a standalone application / fat client. So I think it should solved on the application layer.

Comment: What we need is how to insert the user.name from application layer. 

Regards